# 2 dimensional Ising model: How do we visualize the Hamiltonian for interacting spins, but with no external magnetic field?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, ising-model, partition-function

Suppose we don't have any external magnetic field, so that the Hamiltonian is given by $H=-J\sum_{i,j}s_is_j$. If we have an $n\times n$ 2D lattice of spins. Then does the $H$ correspond to one whole configuration of all the spins, out of all the possible $2^{n\times n}$? How exactly do we compute the $H$ in the 2D case? The 1D case is straightforward, but I'm confused about the 2D case.

Comment: The question is unclear: what does "compute the H" mean? Do you mean "compute the value of the energy given a configuration of spins"?

Comment: Yes. Given a configuration of spins in a 2D lattice, how do we compute the energy $H$? Do we choose one point and only sum over its 4 neighboring spins?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to ask the question properly. So in the 1D case, we have $\sum_is_is_{i+1}$, and we sum over the whole chain. But how do we do that in the 2D version where we don't have a chain, but different points on the lattice? Do we fix a point, and sum over all the points vertically, and horizontally? And then do the same for another point, and sum over all of that? I think it would be good to see an explicit calculation of a $4\times 4$ lattice, for just one configuration.

Comment: It depends on the model. The way you have written it, all spins of the lattice interact with all other spins. But I guess you wanted to only include nearest neighbors interactions, where the sum is written as $\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}$. Is that it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be easier for you to consider a general graph $G = (V,E)$ where $V$ are the vertices and $E$ are the edges. Then a configuration of spins $s \in \{-1,1\}^{V}$ is an assignment of a spin $+1$ or $-1$ to each vertex in the graph. If the vertex is $i$ we call the spin $s_i$.

Each edge $e \in E$ has two endpoints which are vertices and therefore assigned a spin. You could call those endpoints $e_+ $ and $e_-$ and they are both elements of $V$. That is $s_{e_+}$ and $s_{e_-}$ are $+1$ or $-1$ depending in the configuration.

Then you can calculate the Hamiltonian $H$ for one spin configuration by taking
\begin{align*}
H = - J \sum_{e \in E} s_{e_+} s_{e_-}.
\end{align*}
This is easy to do since you just have to sum up some numbers.

Example: Consider graph which has the shape of a triangle $V= \{v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ and edges $e_{12}, e_{2,3}, e_{3,1}$. Suppose that $s_{v_1} =1, s_{v_2} = 1, s_{v_3} = -1 $. Then

\begin{align*}
H = - J \sum_{e \in E} s_{e_+} s_{e_-} = - J ( s_{v_1}s_{v_2} + s_{v_2} s_{v_3} + s_{v_3}  s_{v_1} ) = - J ( 1\cdot 1  + 1 \cdot (-1) +  (-1) \cdot 1) = J. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! so if we have $V=\{ v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \}$ and $s_{v_1}=-1,s_{v_2}=1,s_{v_3}=-1,s_{v_4}=-1$, then $H=-J(s_{v_1}s_{v_2}+s_{v_2}s_{v_3}+s_{v_3}s_{v_4}+s_{v_4}s_{v_1})=-J(-1-1+1+1)=0$? If we have multiple square lattices, we just do the same thing for all points?

Comment: Also, for multiple spin sites connected in squares, would we use the periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: For your first question: That depends on which edges you have between the four vertices!